# R - fill na values sequentially from last nonzero value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe column that looks like this:

```
       a
       <int>
 1     11127
 2     0
 3     0
 4     NA
 5     0
 6     0
 7     NA
 8     0
 9     11580
11     0
12     NA
13     0
```

I want to fill the NA values sequentially from the last nonzero value, so that the end result would look like this:

```
       a
       <int>
 1     11127
 2     0
 3     0
 4     11128
 5     0
 6     0
 7     11129
 8     0
 9     11580
11     0
12     11581
13     0
```

Is there a `dplyr` (preferably) or a base R way of doing this? I was preferring to avoid a for loop since my row count is quite large.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution utilizing `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id = cumsum(!is.na(a) & a != 0)) %>%
 mutate(a = ifelse(is.na(a), first(a) + cumsum(is.na(a)), a))

       a    id
   <int> <int>
 1 11127     1
 2     0     1
 3     0     1
 4 11128     1
 5     0     1
 6     0     1
 7 11129     1
 8     0     1
 9 11580     2
10     0     2
11 11581     2
12     0     2
```

Comment: All are great solutions really. I feel so dumb. This one is my favorite since it is the shortest. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(idx = cumsum(!(is.na(a) | a == 0)), is.na(a)) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(idx) %>%
  mutate(a = coalesce(a, first(a) + rn)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(a)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 1
       a
   <int>
 1 11127
 2     0
 3     0
 4 11128
 5     0
 6     0
 7 11129
 8     0
 9 11580
10     0
11 11581
12     0
```

If speed is an issue, perhaps the `data.table` equivalent will be slightly faster:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, rn := rowid(a), .(cumsum(!(is.na(a) | a == 0)), is.na(a))][
  , a := fcoalesce(a, first(a) + rn), by = cumsum(!(is.na(a) | a == 0))][
    , rn := NULL]
```

*EDIT*

IMO grouping and then getting the row index for `NA`s is not really elegant; it's far better what you can see in other solutions (e.g. using `cumsum`).

Using `fcoalesce`, the issue could then be solved in a single `data.table` step:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, a := fcoalesce(a, first(a) + cumsum(is.na(a))), by = cumsum(!(is.na(a) | a == 0))]
```

Answer (score 4):

A base R approach with `cumsum(logical)` and `ave`.

```
nze <- df1$a != 0 & !is.na(df1$a)
ave(df1$a, cumsum(nze), FUN = function(x){
  na <- is.na(x)
  x[na] <- x[!na][1] + seq_along(which(na))
  x
})
# [1] 11127     0     0 11128     0     0 11129     0 11580     0 11581     0
```

Then assign this result.

```
df1$a <- ave(df1$a, cumsum(nze), FUN = function(x){
  na <- is.na(x)
  x[na] <- x[!na][1] + seq_along(which(na))
  x
})
```